# How to routing to component with same url

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have two components SignInComponent and HomeComponent. I want HomeComponent is a default view of my web app but users must sign in via SignInComponent first and these components has route with same Url. The problem is I dont know how to navigate between them because they has a same Url. Here is my app-routing.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { SignInComponent } from '../components/sign-in/sign-in.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '../components/home/home.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: '', component: SignInComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(
            appRoutes,
            { enableTracing: false }
        )
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

And here is the AuthGuard to checking route access to HomeComponent, it will navigates users to SignInComponent if they are not signed in:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthenticationService) { }

    canActivate() {
        if (this.authService.checkCredentials()) {
            return true;
        }
        this.router.navigate(['']); // The problem is here
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a hard requirement that they must be the same URL? It seems like you might be making this unnecessarily difficult on yourself.

Comment: I agree with axlj.  This kind of goes against the whole point of having routes.  If they have to be on the same route, I would put your `SignInComponent` inside your `HomeComponent` and inside your `HomeComponent` ts file inject your `authService` and put some logic inside your `ngOnInit()` that hides either the `HomeComponenet` content or your `SignInComponent`

Comment: I agree with axlj. Each component should have a single purpose. So consider defining one component for your home page and a separate component for your sign in.

Comment: @axlj No, but I want to find a solution if any. I see a SPA has this so i want to know how to make one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way will be to create a route for your login.

```
const routes : Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#HomeModule'
    }, {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },{
        path: '404',
        component: Page404Component
    }, {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/404'
    }
];
```

and in your home-routing.module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {
       path: '',
       canActivate: [AuthGuard],
       component: HomeComponent,
       children: [...]
   }
]
```

And with a ***guard***, you will redirect to login if the user is not connected.

So The user will no load ALL you app if he isn't connected.